# Tooltip on hover

Tags: html

I want to have a tooltip on my select options on hover. My goal is to give tooltip to options on hover when select box width is decreased

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Select box</title>
<body>
     <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." data-val-required="The CategoryID field is required." id="ddlcat" name="CategoryID">
        <option value="">----Please Select Category----</option>
        <option value="1">Account Opening Email</option>
        <option value="2">Closure Email</option>
        <option value="3">OTP Email</option>
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my Code for select box  ....I tried by giving title to option but it seemed to have no output
`

Comment: Tool-tip is not a default option. you will have to use either CSS or jQuery for the same.

Comment: You want to display *one different tooltip* for each `option`? Or *one common* tooltip for the `select element`?

Comment: <option value="1">Account opening Email</option>   if  I decrease width of my select box "Account opening" is visible.And now if users just hover on select box the option whichever is active should show a title ..........You can refer the code as in if we give title to so that u will get in what way i want my titles to be displayed    <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li><a href="~/AccountMaster/Index" title="Account Master">Account Master</a></li>     </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.
I have done this using jQuery.

```js
$('select').hover(
  function(){var value=$(this).find('option:selected').text();
$('#select_val').text(value).show();
},function(){
$('#select_val').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select box</title>
<body>
     <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." data-val-required="The CategoryID field is required." id="ddlcat" name="CategoryID">
        <option value="">----Please Select Category----</option>
        <option value="1">Account Opening Email</option>
        <option value="2">Closure Email</option>
        <option value="3">OTP Email</option>
        </select>
  <div id="select_val" style="display:none;width:200px;height:20px;position:absolute;top:15px;left:200px;background:aqua;padding:10px;color:black;font-weight:bold;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You Your Approach is very Good ....but can u make it as in title we give for  <a href="" title ="">  You can also refer by above comment in which the question has been asked

Comment: select tag wont allow us to keep title,Its not possible so only i have created a div which will show the currently selected option.

Comment: But can we design it in that way as if i want "In my Comments"

Comment: In the html,you wont be having provision to have a title tag to select box,If at all you keep as <option title="first">first</option>,It wont work.thats what am trying to say.